Is it a mistake or continuity error that Jacob Marley tells Scrooge the spirits would come on 3 successive nights?
In Dickens's A Christmas Carol, Jacob Marley's ghost famously warns Scrooge that he will be visited by three spirits. Jacob's ghost says they will come on three successive nights.

“Without their visits,” said the Ghost, “you cannot hope to shun
the path I tread. Expect the first to-morrow, when the bell tolls One.”
“Couldn’t I take ’em all at once, and have it over, Jacob?” hinted
Scrooge.
“Expect the second on the next night at the same hour. The third
upon the next night when the last stroke of Twelve has ceased to
vibrate."

However, they proceed to come all in the same night. The story begins on Christmas Eve:

Once upon a time—of all the good days in the year, on Christmas Eve—old Scrooge sat busy in his counting-house.

And the story ends on Christmas Day:

“What’s to-day, my fine fellow?” said Scrooge.
“To-day!” replied the boy. “Why, CHRISTMAS DAY.”

There does not appear to be any text in between explaining this, unless I have overlooked something, hence this question. Here is the end of the first spirit:

The Spirit dropped beneath it, so that the extinguisher covered its
whole form; but though Scrooge pressed it down with all his force, he
could not hide the light, which streamed from under it, in an unbroken
flood upon the ground.
He was conscious of being exhausted, and overcome by an
irresistible drowsiness; and, further, of being in his own bed-room. He
gave the cap a parting squeeze, in which his hand relaxed; and had
barely time to reel to bed, before he sank into a heavy sleep.

It immediately goes from there to him awaking to the toll of 1 and the second spirit. Yet how can it be 1 if it was 1 before and he has not awoken and gone through a day? And even if you want to say that it's implied he woke up and went through a day and the 2nd spirit arrives on a separate night, that is an unsatisfactory inference if taken without further explanation since the story very unambiguously ends on Christmas Day, 1 day after the story's opening.
Now, the one other thing is that upon the arrival of the first spirit Scrooge calls out that something weird is going on with time:

To his great astonishment the heavy bell went on from six to
seven, and from seven to eight, and regularly up to twelve; then
stopped. Twelve! It was past two when he went to bed. The clock was
wrong. An icicle must have got into the works. Twelve!

So it seems as if there is time travel or time manipulation at hand, rather than a mistake, but it's so ambiguous that Jacob Marley's statement about 3 successive nights still feels like a mistake.
Can anyone shed light on this little mystery?

As per my answer on the Literature SE about a similar question and indeed, the ghosts seemingly appear on three successive nights, after the clock chimes one the first two times, and right after midnight for the third. Of course, that's not the only time shenanigans going on. With the second ghost, he visits all twelve days of Christmas in the "present".

It was a long night, if it were only a night; but Scrooge had his doubts of this, because the Christmas Holidays appeared to be condensed into the space of time they passed together..... they left a children's Twelfth Night party...

I've found no commentary on Dickens about the significance of how the time passed.

Ah ok so the real authoritative answer then is there isn't a clear answer, only the reader's interpretation. While it seems that the ghosts are (as you say) not moored to time, that is up to interpretation and doesn't clearly explain why Marley said it would be 3 separate nights only to have the experience end the next day. In the absence of a clear textual excerpt or a statement from Dickens, readers are left to draw their own conclusions.
